# regexec corrupt const char * argument

Tags: c, regex, memory

I have this code:

```
char *buffer = calloc(400, sizeof(char));
// buffer gets assigned a string through fgets
if (!regexec(&line_regex, buffer, 400, regmatch_t_var, 0))
    // whatever
```

When the condition is false, the string `buffer` stays as it is (according to gdb).
But when the condition is true, the string `buffer` becomes corrupt (gdb says <error: Cannot access memory at address *0xfffffffffffffffff*>).

That's really strange because as I recall, the address *0xfffffffffffffffff* is the address of the lowest part  of memory, while the heap (`calloc`) initializes bytes at the highest parts of memory.

Can anybody explain what's going on here ?

#### Edit:

Here's an example to help for clarification.

First, create a file named **h** like this: `ps aux > h`

Second, compile this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *out = fopen("h", "r");

    regex_t line_regex;
    regcomp(&line_regex, "(\\w|\\+)+\\s+([0-9]+).+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+ (.+)$", REG_EXTENDED);

    char *buf = calloc(400, sizeof(char));
    regmatch_t pmatch[5];

    /* SegFault when the loop continues after passing the condition */
    while (fgets(buf, 400, out) != NULL)
        if (!regexec(&line_regex, buf, 400, pmatch, 0))
            ;
    fclose(out);
    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

... with `gcc -g`.

Third, inspect the code with gdb and you'll see where the problem lies.

Comment: What command do you give gdb where it gives that error? regexec is defined with the second argument as "const" so it shouldn't be modifying anything there.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I know it shouldn't. The command is: `print buffer` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the way you are calling `regexec`.  You have

```
if (!regexec(&line_regex, buf, 400, pmatch, 0))
                               ^^^ this is wrong
```

`regexec` does not require you to tell it the length of the string to be searched; it uses NUL-termination for that.  The third argument is supposed to be the *number of entries in the `pmatch` array.*  If I change that argument to 5, consistent with the declaration of `pmatch`, your program executes successfully.

You are probably wondering why you have to set this value correctly, considering that your actual regular expression only has three sets of capturing parentheses in it.  Thing is, `regexec` is specified to set the `pmatch` entries for all unmatched capturing groups to `{ -1, -1 }` ... and apparently this implementation does that by filling the entire `pmatch` array, as sized by its third argument, with `{ -1, -1 }` ahead of time.  So, it writes past the end of the declared array and clobbers the `buf` pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I wasn't focused enough when reading the man pages !

Answer (score -1):

The code above is correct; the error is probably elsewhere.

The first thing you should do is to write down the result of `calloc()` and dump the memory there when the condition is true. My guess is that the string itself is still good but the *pointer* `buffer` gets overwritten.

Remember: `buffer` is a name for an address on the stack (somewhere in the local stack frame of your function). If you have buffer overflow in some other local variable, then the local stack frame can become corrupted and you would see something like pointers suddenly pointing to odd memory locations.

Comment: I changed the name buffer to buf just to be assured, and the result is still the same. Also, your guess is correct, I created a void * to point to buf and after the regexec() call, its value changed to ___0xffffffffffff__ itself. After inspecting the memory address where the string was stored before the call with gdb, it appears the string itself is fine.

Comment: So someone is overwriting your memory. Try to set a watchpoint on the pointer (i.e. `&buffer`) so the code stops when someone writes to it. Since watchpoints are pretty expensive, set a breakpoint on the `if()`, install the watchpoint when it's hit and then continue.

Comment: The watchpoint triggers immediately when the `if()` is executed